# Why .htaccess dose not route to my index.php?

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, routes

I have created `.htaccess` with content of:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
IndexIgnore */*
# Turn on the RewriteEngine
RewriteEngine On
#  Rules
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . index.php
```

So, I am expecting: http://mydomain.com/command/paramater1 to be directed to index.php, but that dose not happen, instead, I get 404 error.

However, http://mydomain.com will open `index.php`

The directory of my website looks like this:

public_html/index.php
public_html/.htaccess

I have `mod_rewrite` enabled.

Any idea?

**EDIT**

What I am expecting when `http://mydomain.com/command/paramater1` is to read the command in the url in index.php and act accordingly, but as I mentioned, index.php is not opened, instead 404 error

Comment: U want to rewrite everything to index ? use `^` instead of `.`

Comment: Can you please write the correct .htaccess by adding an answer to this question? Thanks

Comment: You're on an Apache server? Windows servers ignore .htaccess unless you have a special plug-in of some sort, and I don't think nginx uses the same format.

Comment: Yes, I am on Apache server, not windows...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    Options -MultiViews

    RewriteEngine On
    #RewriteBase /path/to/app
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [QSA,L]
</IfModule>
```

This will reroute every page to index.php when mod_rewrite module is active

Comment: . would have worked just as well. All you're looking to do is match _anything_.

Comment: yes, both . and ^ worked, but can you please explain Options -MultiViews VS Options +FollowSymLinks ? also what does !-f and !-d mean? [QSA,L] ?